# How do I modify email headers when using Rules to send mail?

Tags: rules, emails

I'm using the Drupal 7 [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module to trigger and send emails on specific events, but need to modify the email headers before the message is sent.

What would be the appropriate way to add 'reply-to' headers (as used in [RFC 5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322)) to specific outgoing emails that are sent using the Drupal 7 Rules module?

The following works when using [drupal_mail](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!mail.inc/function/drupal_mail/7)() but I do not see how to apply this hook when using [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules).

```
function hook_mail($key, &$message, $params) {
    switch ($key) {
        case 'key_name_here':
            $message['Reply-to'] = $params['mail'];
            $message['subject'] = $params['subject'];
            $message['body'] = $params['body'];
            $message['headers']['Reply-To'] = $params['mail'];
            break;    
    }
}
// One note to the above script, lines 4 and 7 seem redundant and likely need work.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use hook_mail, you just need to identify the key for the rule or rules you want to override. The key is set in the rules_action_mail() function `$key = 'rules_action_mail_' . $name . '_' . $element->elementId();` where name is the rule name and element id is the numeric id for the rule. You need to make sure your custom module has a higher weight that the rules module in the system table of your database.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I should have over rules_action_mail() before posting, but wouldn't have found it without your suggestion.  Thank you.